# Drawbacks of using jQuery to cycle through images on a website

Tags: php, jquery

I've created a comics website, http://www.hittingtreeswithsticks.com/, where if you click on a comic thumbnail it will take you to the full size of the image (the viewimage.php template).

On the viewimage.php template, I'm using javascript/jquery to cycle through images I've stored in an array so that users will not have to reload the page each time.

**There seems to be two problems with this:**

1) I also have a "like/dislike" feature I'd like to add... so that you can vote per image, as well as a facebook like button (so the user can like PER IMAGE). Currently, since jQuery is cycling through the images, it's not updating the id for that image you clicked on. (In this image, if I press right arrow key to go next, the id should increment to 35).

[image]

[image]

2) Eventually I'd like to make money off of Ad Revenue. Sources say that if I use jQuery to get the next image, instead of reloading the page, the Ad won't be refreshed... and I'll generate a lot less ad revenue.

So, my question is... is it possible for Jquery to handle these issues, or do I have to do page refreshes to increment the IDs and refresh the Ads?

Thanks!

EDIT: I've added in

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, 'http://www.hittingtreeswithsticks.com/?action=viewimage&site=comics&id=imgIndex');
```

Code (this doesn't seem to  be working, and in fact blocks the "next" code from working)

```
    $("#next").click(function() {
        imgIndex++;
            if (imgIndex > imgArray.length-1) 
            {
                imgIndex = 0;
            }
            img.src = imgArray[imgIndex];
            window.history.pushState(null, null, 'http://www.hittingtreeswithsticks.com/?action=viewimage&site=comics&id=imgIndex');
    });
```

UPDATED:

Error:

[image]

Comment: jQuery is not the issue.  It's how you program your function or configure your plugin.

Comment: @Sparky672 My apologies. Can you elaborate on your first comment please?

Comment: You could use ajax to refresh/load content without refreshing the page, for example.  This is how you program your jQuery or JS... not whether or not jQuery can handle it.

Comment: @Sparky672 Ah okay, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first problem, you can use [pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method). At the time you replace the image, you can also update the url. This adds a new history entry and replaces the url in the browser, but doesn't actually reload the page. Example:

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, 'http://www.hittingtreeswithsticks.com/?action=viewimage&site=comics&id=N&cat=&title=TITLE');
```

(Just replace N and TITLE appropriately here). So that solves that. Note that this is not a jQuery feature, but vanilla javascript.

Regarding issue 2, it depends on how your ads are set up, but that's probably the case that they won't be automatically reloaded. In most cases, you can also reload the ads via javascript, but the specifics would depend upon the details of how your ads are served; you should probably post a separate question asking how to load ads asynchronously via javascript and give the specifics of how your ad server works.

Comment: Thanks Ben! I've never even heard of something like pushState()... where do you guys find all of these things? Haha. I wish I was more resourceful. And, good idea to post a separate question about loading ads asynchronously. Thanks again.

Comment: Ben, just got around to trying this. It doesn't seem to be working. I've updated my question at the bottom

Comment: @Growler, well one thing I notice in your question is that you are literally passing in `imgIndex`; you need to append the variable instead, like this: `window.history.pushState(null, null, 'http://www.hittingtreeswithsticks.com/?action=viewimage&site=comics&id=' + imgIndex);`. But I don't know why it's blocking the function; it should work fine. Do you see any error messages in the javascript console?

Comment: "Object Doesn't Support this Property or Method". See updated q above for image.